# Why is the Discriminant always an integer?

Tags: polynomials, field-theory, galois-theory, discriminant

In my Galois theory notes, I read that we define the $discriminant$ of a degree $n$ polynomial $f$ with roots $\alpha_1, ... , \alpha_n $ as

$$\Delta^2 = (-1)^{n(n-1)/2}\prod\limits_{i\ne j}(\alpha_i-\alpha_j)$$

And when I look at the discriminants of various low degree polynomials (over the integers) I notice that they are always integers:

$n = 2:{\displaystyle b^{2}-4ac\,}$

$n=3:{\displaystyle b^{2}c^{2}-4ac^{3}-4b^{3}d-27a^{2}d^{2}+18abcd\,}$

${n=4:\displaystyle {\begin{aligned}{}&256a^{3}e^{3}-192a^{2}bde^{2}-128a^{2}c^{2}e^{2}+144a^{2}cd^{2}e\\&{}-27a^{2}d^{4}+144ab^{2}ce^{2}-6ab^{2}d^{2}e-80abc^{2}de\\&{}+18abcd^{3}+16ac^{4}e-4ac^{3}d^{2}-27b^{4}e^{2}+18b^{3}cde\\&{}-4b^{3}d^{3}-4b^{2}c^{3}e+b^{2}c^{2}d^{2}\,\end{aligned}}}$

Etc. So the question I want to ask is; is this always the case? If so, how do we prove this? And more importantly, if we look at arbitrary polynomials in the ring $K[t]$ for some base field $K$, is the discriminant always in the base field $K$?

Many thanks.

Comment: Product of integers is an integer.

Comment: Sum and difference of integers are integers

Comment: Powe of integers are integers.

Comment: If there are no division or roots... you cannot go outside integers.

Comment: Yes, $K $ is the unique field which is fixed by all elements of the Galois group. What happens when you apply the automorphism from the splitting field of your polynomial to $\delta^2$?

Comment: Ahh, I see now how this follows from the Galois correspondence. Thanks!

Comment: The discriminant of the polynomial $f(x)=3x^2-1$, $\Delta=(\alpha_1-\alpha_2)^2=(2/\sqrt3)^2=4/3$ is not an integer. I know what you meant, but please be precise :-)

Comment: And, good job realizing how this is related to the Galois correspondence!

Answer (score 3):

[Another definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant#Definition) of the discriminant of a polynomial
$
f(x) = a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1x+a_0
$
is
$$
\Delta = \frac{(-1)^\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}{a_n}\operatorname{resultant}(f,f')
$$
The [resultant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant) is a determinant with entries in $K$ and so is in $K$.

For a monic polynomial with coefficients in a ring $R$, the discriminant is in $R$.

Answer (score 1):

Take any element of the Galois group $g \in \operatorname{Gal}(f)$ and consider how it acts on the discriminant: $$g(\Delta^2) = (-1)^{n(n-1)/2} \prod_{i \neq j}(g(\alpha_i) - g(\alpha_j))$$

Now $g$ permutes the roots $\alpha_i$ in some order, but since the product runs over all $i \neq j$, we still get all $(\alpha_i - \alpha_j)$ turning up in the product. We deduce that $g(\Delta^2) = \Delta^2$ and so, by Galois theory, $\Delta^2 \in \mathbb{Q}$.

Your definition of the discriminant assumes that $f$ is monic. In this case, the roots $\alpha_i$ are algebraic integers, and therefore so is $\Delta^2$.

Putting this together, $\Delta^2$ is both a rational number and an algebraic integer, hence a rational integer $\Delta^2 \in \mathbb{Z}$.